# Java - 4 Threads manipulate within two synchronized methods the same object data

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronized

first of all I am very new here, so I hope I will do all things right during questioning.

The problem:

I have a class `Store` with an attribute `int size;`

In this class are two methods to manipulate the `size` attribute.

```
`public synchronized void leave(){
   this.size++;
}`

`public synchronized void enter(){
   while(this.size==0){ }
   this.size--;
}`
```

If I initialize the Store Object with `size=2;`for example and 4 other objects (the 4 threads)
alternately try to `leave()` or `enter()`the `Store object` I will get an endless loop. 
I thought if I write synchronized methods, the leave method could also be called by a thread although a other thread will hang in the endless loop.

I hope my question is understandable.
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: The lock is on the object, not the method.  Two threads can enter the same method for different objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> first of all I am very new here, so I hope I will do all things right
>   during questioning.

Your question is asked well so you got at least that right :)

> 4 other objects (the 4 threads) alternately try to leave() or
>   enter()the Store object I will get an endless loop

When one thread enters the synchronized block, you are declaring that no other threads can enter a synchronized region of the same object until the thread has left the initial synchronized block.  What you have is a thread invoking `enter` and spinning until size is 0. For that to happen, size needs to be incremented, which cannot happen because another thread cannot invoke `leave` (while the other thread is spinning for ever).

**Solution**

Instead of busy spinning ( `while(<some condition>){ }` ), have the thread `wait` on the monitor.  This will give up the lock so another thread can enter.  And after `leave`ing, notify any waiting threads.

```
public synchronized void leave(){
   this.size++;
   this.notify();
}

public synchronized void enter(){
   while(this.size==0){ 
       this.wait();
   }
   this.size--;
}
```

Comment: Wow, incredible fast. Thank you! "... no other thread can enter a synchronized region of the same object " means that it is not limited on the same synchronized method ?

Comment: Correct! It is limited on the instance.

Comment: Yep, that's the whole point of the `synchronized` keyword. If you wanted to do it at the function level, you'd need a `mutex`.

Answer (score 0):

On the same note as other solution you can consider the folowing solution too. It is better in 2 things
1. instead of synchronizing on method reduce lock scope
2. much clear approach thank using the wait-notify solution

```
class ConditionExample {
    final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    final Condition resourceAvailable = lock.newCondition();

    private int size = 2;

    public void leave() throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            size++;
            //signal other waiting threads
            resourceAvailable.signal();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void enter() throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            //Check condition
            while (size == 0)
                resourceAvailable.await();
            size--;
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.